# Searching multiple values through multiple columns

Tags: php, jquery, sql

I'm looking to create a search as such https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuYZk.png

Basically it'll look through my database looking for the values that people input.

There will be different values for each combo box (up to 5 or so). I need to somehow determine what values the user uses and with those values I need to create a search accordingly. I tried building a string builder with get requests however that was too insecure.

The issue here is there is one value which is "Any" meaning i will need it to retrieve any kind of value.

I would need to somehow `"SELECT FROM DATABASE WHERE ITEM = ANY"` if that makes sense.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `5 combos/selects` and each one contains a `All` so to determine the `All` you can set a value for `All`, for example :

```
<option value="none">All</option>
```

So, you can check on the server whether it's `none` submitted or not by something like this

```
$where = array();
$where['country'] = (isset($_GET['country']) && $_GET['country'] != 'none') ? filter_var($_GET['country'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) : null;
$where['state'] = (isset($_GET['state']) && $_GET['state'] != 'none') ? filter_var($_GET['state'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) : null;
// Rest of them ....

$where_str = ' where ';
foreach($where as $field => $value) {
    if(!is_null($value)) {
        if(strlen($where_str) > 6) $where_str .= ' and ';
        $where_str .= "$field = '$value'";
    }
}
```

So far, you'll get a string like `where country = 'Bangladesh' and holiday_cost = '1000'` or only `where` (depending on user selection), so you can check if anything you have in where clause like

```
// At first your basic/default query
$sql = "select * from tablename";

// Now, if $where_str contains more than where, then add it
if(strlen($where_str) > 6) {
    $sql .= $where;
}
```

Now, your sql query is ready and you can run your query from here. Don't forget to `filter` inputs and you can use [filter-var](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) for that.

Comment: `$where['country'] = isset($_GET['country'] && $_GET['country'] != 'none') ? filter_var($_GET['country'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) : null;


$where['state'] = isset($_GET['state'] && $_GET['state'] != 'none') ? filter_var($_GET['state'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) : null;` No idea why.. Edited with Dreamweaver

Comment: My mistake, it should be `$where['country'] = isset($_GET['country']) && $_GET['country'] != 'none' ? filter_var($_GET['country'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) : null; $where['state'] = isset($_GET['state'] && $_GET['state'] != 'none') ? filter_var($_GET['state'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) : null;`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to build the sql statement. For example:

```
$whr = "";
$srch1 = ( isset($_POST['suburb']) ) ? $_POST['suburb'] : "";
//-- repeat for each field
if( $srch1 != "" ) $whr .= " suburb like '%'.%srch1."%'";

$sql ="SELECT ... FROM ... ";
if( $whr != "" ) $sql .= " WHERE ".$whr;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since SQL differentiates between data types and even if a value was given for a particular `field` the `any` value would always need to be composed of two `OR`-connected parts:

1. `field =`"a generous data range that includes any posible existing value ..."
2. `field IS NULL`

For numeric types 1. gets a bit complicated and would have to be something like

```
field IS BETWEEN MIN(<numeric type>) AND MAX(<numeric type>)
```

For string types it is a little bit simpler:

```
field LIKE '%'
```

But in any case these search criteria will never be as simple as you would like them to be *and* they will cost unnecessary search effort for the SQL server!

So, I guess, your first approach of building a SQL search string is still the method to be applied here. You wil have to put some effort into that but I think it *can* be made *safe* nonetheless.

In similar projects I have used a pattern generator in which I put together a search criterion for each field. The pattern generator needs to know the field's name, type and posibly table name and of course the user input. Then, dependent on whether anything was actually input it churns out either

- nothing (`null`) --> no comparison!
- a valid search condition like `field LIKE '<processed user input>` or `field =``or`field BETWEEN `user min value` AND `user max value`

Since the user input will *always be processed* according to the data type of the given  `field` (including of course a final call of something like `mysqli_real_escape_string()`) you *can* make the whole thing safe.

After you processed all the fields with it's user input you need to put all generated (not the `null`) criteria together again (surround them with `(`, `)`, collect them in an array (`$arr`) and finally `join(' AND ',$arr)` them) and if necessary, determine which tables (assuming there will be `JOIN`s) are involved. These `JOINS` can now also be applied conditionally depending on certain crieteria being given or not. This of course really depends on the deeper logic of your table setup.